# Print Out Variables Passed Into Functions

Tags: r

I come from a python background but I'm new to R (need to learn it in a hurry), stuck at an issue:

I am developing a function to print out the variables passed into my function, kinda simple.

```
hello_world <- function(fn, num) {
    print("The stuff you sent in were "$fn" and "$num")
}
```

so if I call hello world as such:

```
hello_world("foo", 3:5)
```

I should see

```
The stuff you sent in were "foo" and "3:5"
```

I tried print("$foo", "$num")...still having issues. How can I do this without using sprint?

Comment: Remove the `$`, from `fn` and `num` and use `paste` i.e. `paste("The stuff you sent in were", fn, ' and ', num)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `deparse/substitute` to get the input as it is from 'num', and then create a single string with `paste`

```
hello_world <- function(fn, num) {
      num <- deparse(substitute(num))
      cat(paste0("The stuff you sent in were ", '"', fn, '"',
              " and ", '"', num, '"'), "\n")
                    }
```

-testing

```
> hello_world("foo", 3:5)
The stuff you sent in were "foo" and "3:5"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `paste` to assemble the string to be printed.
And note that since `3:5` is a vector, the first `paste` uses argument `collapse`.
I have also included 3 different ways of printing.

```r
hello_world <- function(fn, num) {
  num_string <- paste(num, collapse = ",")
  msg <- paste("The stuff you sent in were", dQuote(fn), "and", dQuote(num_string))
  # 3 ways of printing
  print(msg)
  cat(msg, "\n")    # needs the newline character
  message(msg)      # this will default to printing in red
} 
hello_world("foo", 3:5)
#> [1] "The stuff you sent in were “foo” and “3,4,5”"
#> The stuff you sent in were “foo” and “3,4,5”
#> The stuff you sent in were “foo” and “3,4,5”
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Just use `cat` instead of `print` ,

```r
hello_world <- function(fn, num) {
  cat("The stuff you sent in were \"" , fn , "\" and \"" , num , "\"" , sep = "")
} 

hello_world("foo", 3:5)
#> The stuff you sent in were "foo" and "345"

hello_world("foo", "3:5")
#> The stuff you sent in were "foo" and "3:5"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option where you don't have to specify your parameters:

```r
library(purrr)

hello_world <- function(fn, num) {
  params <- as.character(match.call()[-1])
  out <- sub(paste(map_chr(params, ~paste("`", ., "`",  " and")), collapse = ' '), pattern = " [[:alpha:]]*$", replacement = "")
  paste0('The stuff you sent in were ', out)
} 

hello_world('foo', 3:5)
#> [1] "The stuff you sent in were ` foo `  and ` 3:5 ` "
```

So you could extend this to something like:

```r
library(purrr)

hello_world <- function(fn, num, apple, banana, cheeseburger) {
  params <- as.character(match.call()[-1])
  out <- sub(paste(map_chr(params, ~paste("`", ., "`",  " and")), collapse = ' '), pattern = " [[:alpha:]]*$", replacement = "")
  paste0('The stuff you sent in were ', out)
} 

hello_world('foo', 3:5, 'yes', 'no', 'definitely')
#> [1] "The stuff you sent in were ` foo `  and ` 3:5 `  and ` yes `  and ` no `  and ` definitely ` "
```